# C++, SDL2, OpenGL - Баг с цветом текста

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl2

Использую SDL_ttf для показа текста.

Код:

```
#include "Text.hpp"
using namespace fox;

Text::Text(){
    TTF_Init();
    textPolygon.setPointCount(4);
}

void Text::loadFont(std::string path, int size){
    font=TTF_OpenFont(path.c_str(), size);
}

void Text::setFillColor(Color color){
    textColor.r=color.rgb.r;
    textColor.g=color.rgb.g;
    textColor.b=color.rgb.b;
    textColor.a=0;

    mainColor=color.rgb;
}

void Text::setSize(float width, float height){
    size.width=width; size.height=height;
    textPolygon.setPointSize(0, 0, 0);
    textPolygon.setPointSize(1, width, 0);
    textPolygon.setPointSize(2, width, height);
    textPolygon.setPointSize(3, 0, height);

    position.y-=size.height/4;
}

void Text::setPosition(float x, float y){
    position.x=x; position.y=y;
}

void Text::setText(std::string text){
    textSurface=TTF_RenderText_Blended(font, 
                    text.c_str(), textColor);
    
    glGenTextures(1, &fontID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fontID);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textSurface->w, 
        textSurface->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 
                                    textSurface->pixels);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);

    setSize(textSurface->w, textSurface->h);
}

void Text::show(){
    glPushMatrix();
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);

    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glTranslatef(getPosition().x,
                 getPosition().y, 0);
    glBegin(GL_POLYGON);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 0); textPolygon.getPoint(0);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 0); textPolygon.getPoint(1);
        glTexCoord2f(1, 1); textPolygon.getPoint(2);
        glTexCoord2f(0, 1); textPolygon.getPoint(3);
    glEnd();

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glPopMatrix();
}

Vector2f Text::getPosition(){
    return position;
}

Rectf Text::getSize(){
    return size;
}

Color::RGB Text::getFillColor(){
    return mainColor;
}
```

Когда я выставляю красный цвет то показывает синий да и вообще со всеми цветами так, кроме белого!

Почему так?

Comment: Сейчас заплачу ; )

Comment: видимо надо задать textColor.a=1.0